# Isabelle: How to unify type variables of current and imported locale?

Tags: isabelle

Consider this following contrived example of locale declarations in Isabelle:

```
locale x =
  fixes f :: "'a ⇒ 'a"
  assumes "f ∘ f = f"

locale y = x +
  fixes g :: "'a ⇒ 'b"
begin
  abbreviation h :: "'a ⇒ 'b" where "h ≡ g ∘ f"
end
```

This fails, because the `'a` in locale `x` is different from the `'a` in locale `y`. How can I tell Isabelle that the argument of `g` should have the same type as the argument and the result of `f`?

Comment: One solution would be to replace `locale y = x +` by `locale y = x f for f :: "'a ⇒ 'a" +`. However, this would mean repeating the type of `f`. Such repetition would be particularly cumbersome if the type is rather complex.

Comment: Note that you can use dummy patterns also, hence `locale y = x f for f :: "'a ⇒ _" +` is sufficient and would remain readable also for complex type expressions.